# plotting a density plot and a scatter plot on the same figure

Tags: r, plot

I will like replicate the combined plot of density plot and scatter plot as in Figure 3 of of this paper:

```
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6222032/
```

[image]

I will like to do this in base R or any R package. I know how to plot both density plot and scatter plot but not how to combine the two as in the paper. Can anyone suggest anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.3, fill = "gray70", color = "white") +
  geom_jitter(aes(y = -5), height = 3, alpha = 0.2) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Could add `geom_line(data = data.frame(density(iris$Sepal.Width)[c("x", "y")]), aes(x, y * 50))`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jon Spring

Comment: Thanks @d.b I'm guessing the geom_line(....) line will add density plot. Right? For some reason, after adding the line to the Jon's code above and running, density plot was not added.